# Android SearchView overlapping

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to build a searchview who is fixed on top of the page.
When i scroll down my searchview is overlapped by a imageslider [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnuSf.png) all i need to do is to be always in front to be visible.
I tried everything but always my searchview is in the back of other objects. Any suggestions?

This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="@string/searchint"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
            android:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
            android:queryHint="SEARCH PRODUCTS"
            android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/email"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/email"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:autofillHints="@string/parola"
                    android:drawablePadding="10sp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/parola"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:padding="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:buttonTint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingStart="30sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                app:iss_corner_radius="5"
                app:iss_delay="0"
                app:iss_period="1000"></com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use elevation to make it at top of other elements

**Solution Code**:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="@string/searchint"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
        android:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:queryHint="SEARCH PRODUCTS"
        android:theme="@style/SearchViewStyle" />
```

For instance, I used 20dp, you use your preferred value instead.

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: Glad to help you. Kindly upvote the answer.